# Solutions to the complex equation $z^n=w$ with one solution given

Tags: complex-numbers

In an old test paper $z_0=2+i$ is given as one solution to $z^4=-7+24i$ and we are asked to find further solutions.

In the solution is given

$$z_1=-z_0=-2-i$$ as $$z^4_1=(-1)^4z_0^4=z_0^4$$ I assume this to be a typo and should read $=-z_0^4$

Then is given further that $$z_2=iz_0=-1+2i$$ $$z_3=-iz_0=1-2i$$

Can someone explain to me why this is true? Is is something to with complex conjugates or with powers of $i$?

Thanks!

Comment: More generally, if $z_0$ solves $z^n=u$ for some $u\ne0$, then the $n$ solutions of $z^n=u$ are $z_0$, $z_0\omega$, $z_0\omega^2$, ... , and $z_0\omega^{n-1}$, where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/n}$ is the primitive $n$th root of unity. In your case, $n=4$ hence $\omega=i$ and the roots are $z_0$, $iz_0$, $-z_0$, and $-iz_0$. Note that if $z_0=2+i$, these are $z_0=2+i$, $iz_0=-1+2i$, $-z_0=-2-i$, and $-iz_0=1-2i$.

Comment: @Did fantastic! Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Between the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and the Factor Theorem, if you find $n$ distinct roots to $z^n=w$ then you are done and there are no more.

Look at each of $(-z_0)^4$, $(iz_0)^4$ and $(-iz_0)^4$.

In general, if $z_0^n=w$ then multiplying $z_0$ by the $n-1$ $n$-th roots of unity (that aren't one) gives $n-1$ more solutions to $z^n=w$ and so you have them all by the above theorems.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $(1)^4=(-1)^4=i^4=(-i)^4$ so all these are the solutions of the given equation.